# Can you have a SELECT Statement create two rows when a case condtion is met?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

I have a table that contains a breakdown of some data. I want to have that every 12 rows there is a row containing the total for the previous 12 rows. My understanding is that I cannot insert a row at a specific place in a table.
So i am attempting to create a second table that selects the data from the first table and on a case condition being met adds the total row.

This is my current attempt:

```
INSERT INTO @loanTempTable2 (payment,principal,interest,regular)
    SELECT
        (CASE 
            WHEN MonthNumber%12!=0
            THEN CAST(MonthNumber AS varchar(50))
            ELSE 'Year Total'
        END) AS payment,
        (CASE
            WHEN MonthNumber%12=0
            THEN (SELECT SUM(principal) FROM @loanTempTable WHERE payment BETWEEN (MonthNumber-11) AND MonthNumber)
            WHEN MonthNumber=@LoanPeriod
            THEN (SELECT SUM(principal) FROM @loanTempTable WHERE payment BETWEEN (@LoanPeriod-(@LoanPeriod%12)+1) AND @LoanPeriod)
            ELSE (@RegularPayment - (@Rate*@LoanAmount))*(POWER((@Rate+1),(MonthNumber-1)))
        END) AS principal,
        (CASE
            WHEN MonthNumber%12=0
            THEN (SELECT SUM(interest) FROM @loanTempTable WHERE payment BETWEEN (MonthNumber-11) AND MonthNumber)
            WHEN MonthNumber=@LoanPeriod
            THEN (SELECT SUM(interest) FROM @loanTempTable WHERE payment BETWEEN (@LoanPeriod-(@LoanPeriod%12)+1) AND @LoanPeriod)
            ELSE @RegularPayment - (@RegularPayment - (@Rate*@LoanAmount))*(POWER((@Rate+1),(AM.MonthNumber-1)))
        END) AS interest,
        (CASE
            WHEN MonthNumber%12=0
            THEN (SELECT SUM(regular) FROM @loanTempTable WHERE payment BETWEEN (MonthNumber-11) AND MonthNumber)
            WHEN MonthNumber=@LoanPeriod
            THEN (SELECT SUM(regular) FROM @loanTempTable WHERE payment BETWEEN (@LoanPeriod-(@LoanPeriod%12)+1) AND @LoanPeriod)
            ELSE @RegularPayment
        END) AS regular
    FROM AllowedMonths AM
    WHERE AM.MonthNumber >= 1 AND AM.MonthNumber <= @LoanPeriod
```

However, this is not working as I need it to, because it causes one of the payments to be skipped. The table results in having a total row where say the payment 12 row was.

My question is whether there is a way to have two rows added each time the case

`WHEN MonthNumber%12=0`

Occurs, hopefully meaing the payment 12 and the total row would appear in the table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is always tricky to handle in SQL - if possible, I'd simply handle this at the presentation level or somesuch.

If you persist in trying to do this in SQL, one way to do this would be by moveing the `case` to a join:

```
-- setup test data
declare @data table ([month] int)

declare @i int;

set @i = 1;
while @i < 100
begin
    insert into @data values (@i);
    set @i = @i + 1;
end;

with expander (idx) as
(
  select 1
  union all
  select 2
)
select
 case when E.idx = 1 then cast(D.[month] as varchar) else 'Year total' end as [month]

from @data D
left join expander E on E.idx = 1 or (D.[month] % 12 = 0)
```

The idea should be pretty obvious. You can do whatever aggregations you want with windowed functions:

```
case 
 when E.idx = 1 then D.[month] 
 else sum(D.[month]) over (partition by (D.[month] - 1) / 12) - D.[month]
end
```

A more reasonable (and easier to read and use) approach would be to take the two queries separately, then union them, and finally, order them by the month again. This makes much more sense, and is a lot easier to maintain - you don't have to do the silly "If I'm in a total row, emit this value, otherwise, emit this value".

Comment: thank you @Luaan for the speedy response! I think i understand what youre getting at, so ill give that a go! I wanted to use the union and order by method, but wouldnt that result in the totals rows all being at the bottom?

Comment: @A.Goodsell Not if you handle the ordering properly - the easiest way would be to `order by [MonthNumber], [IsTotal]`, where `[IsTotal]` will be `1` for the totals and `0` for others, and `[MonthNumber]` for the totals would be the last month the total applies to.